# algorithm for arranging coordinates of corner points of a hexahedron in order

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a set of randomly ordered 8 corner vortexes of a `hexahedron`

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)   
(0.0, 1.5, 0.0)   
(1.5, 1.5, 0.0)   
(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)  
(0.0, 1.5, 1.5)  
(1.5, 0.0, 1.5)  
(1.5, 0.0, 0.0)  
(0.0, 0.0, 1.5)
```

I need algorithm to arrange these points in an order. for eg first i want to print the 4 points of the front face and then the other 4 points of the back face(both in clockwise direction).  the above points are uniformly spaced (like a `cube`). I need algorithm for `hexahedron`.

Comment: Then you'll need to define, in terms of your coordinate system, what you mean by "front" and what you mean by "clockwise". But in any case, do you really need to rearrange this particular list? Why not just grab the extents of the hexahedron with min/max, and then print out new points representing those faces?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. show us the code, what you have done already.

Comment: Are there any other constraints? Will the hexahedron always have one corner at (0,0,0)?

Comment: For a hexahedron, you can find the coordinate of the centre of each face by averaging each corner's coordinate. You can then draw the faces in order of the z-index of the face coordinates (if this is what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: The given coordinates are only for one hexahedron( stated as example). In my actual case there will be millions of hexehedrons in the 3d mesh. so there will not be case that one corner will be at (0,0,0), it is random. for each hexahedron i have set of 8 points stored in a data structure. Which are infact randomly ordered. The order is different for each hexahedron. For each hexahedron, i need to rearrange in a same order. For this purpose i stated query for one hexahedron.

Comment: Using the word [hexahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron) might not be what you want, because it doesn't need to have 8 vertices. Maybe you ought to use the word [quadrilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/quadrilateral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "algorithm" you ask for is actually a simple sorting of the vertices such that they will be ordered in the way you want. The following function does this:

```
void order_hexa(double points[8][3])
{
    double tmp;
    int i,j,k,l,m,n=8;

    k= n-1; // k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted.
    while (k > 0)
    {
        l= 0;
        for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if ( /*z*/ points[j][2] >  points[j+1][2]
            || ( /*x*/ points[j][2] == points[j+1][2] && points[j][0] >  points[j+1][0])
            || ( /*y*/ points[j][2] == points[j+1][2] && points[j][0] == points[j+1][0] && points[j][1] > points[j+1][1]) )
            {
                for (m=0; m<3; m++) {
                    tmp           = points[j]  [m];
                    points[j]  [m]= points[j+1][m];
                    points[j+1][m]= tmp;
                }
                l= j;
            }
        }
        k= l;
    }
}
```

This is a simple bubble sort. Though bubble sort is generally slow (O(n^2)), it is efficient on small samples, such as here with only 8 elements.