# Arranging corner points of a hexahedron by coordinates

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geometry

I have a list of 8 points given by their coordinates (x, y, z).

These 8 points are the 8 vertices of an hexahedron, which means that there are 6 faces which are quadrilaterals; the 4 points on each face are guaranteed to be coplanar.

I want to sort the list of points in a particular order:

- the first 4 points must be on the same face, and in counterclockwise order;
- the next 4 points must be their corresponding points on the opposite face.

Example:

[image: Example hexahedron with ordered vertices]

I found [similar question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599245/algorithm-for-arranging-coordinates-of-corner-points-of-a-hexahedron-in-order), but this algorithm fails on this example hexahedron:
[image: Second example, the algorithm fails on this one]

I also have an idea to sort points in direct way by finding points in the same plane, then the other point in this plane, then point on same edge and etc.

But is there any easier way to order these points?